# Java: "customize" webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html

I have looked around and could not find any threads with a solution to this yet. I am trying to make a program for a specific website, it interacts with the website just like user would do and it does so how the user wants it to interact. I'm using Selenium right now and just grabing WebDriver and making it do a list of tasks, but I want the WebDriver to interact how the user would want it to.

So is there any way to lay a "skin" on the WebDriver? So like a button where if selected it does a certain task? And is there a way to remove the URL bar and make a gradient border around the Browser to make it look like a program? Or should I be using something else in order to accomplish this?

Here is an "image" of what it would look like:
http://i39.tinypic.com/okn0rd.jpg

Where only the black is visible and the brown isn't there, or not visible and there are "buttons" over?

So would this be possible with any WebDriver through Selenium or should I be using other ways to interact with the webpage in order to accomplish this? Don't need to do my homework for me, but I would appreciate refrences to where I could do this. I was thinking of using HTMLUnit and just making a headless browser that does all this in the background and prints a picture and I can display that in a Java Program with all the buttons over it?

Comment: In spite of the explanation, I dont understand why and what you want...

Comment: I want to make a program, It interacts with a website. User selects options and the program executes based on what the user selects. Is it possible to make a button on Selenium WebDriver that can be clicked on, or would I need to interact with a website a different way?

Comment: @Riven, what do you mean when you say "make a button on Selenium WebDriver"? Selenium webdriver is not a stand alone application.

Comment: I think he's saying that he wants to create a Java based program that has several buttons and form controls that a given user clicks or fills out. These would be the inputs that are then passed to the WebDriver script and executed to automate the browser for the user while they watch.

Comment: Yes, I meant what bgoad said.

Comment: There is no native way to do this, it is extra logic you'd need to build on top. Break it down into chunks of work and attack it that way. This could easily be done by creating a Java app of some kind, and just passing commands to the WebDriver - but there is no way to do this out of the box.

Comment: @Arran If I were to make a Java App how would I display the image of the page to the app? Just keep taking screen shots and uploading them every second?